# Charging a metal by extracting electrons from it?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, electrons

Suppose we have a field emission electron gun as shown in the figure, (let's ignore the voltage of the second anode), the voltage of the first anode is to extract electrons from the cathode, there is generally a range of voltages in the electrons are extracted from the cathode (the higher the voltage, the greater the electron current).
[image]
Initially there is a potential difference between anode and cathode such that the emission of electrons begins, if the electrons do not return to the cathode it will begin to be positively charged and therefore the potential difference will be less and less. Until it reaches a limit and the potential between anode and cathode is no longer sufficient to extract electrons.

Is there any paper that studies this phenomenon of positively charging a metal by extracting electrons from it? I need to confirm if this method has already been tested.

Comment: Well, the metal has some capacitance to ground, so if not grounded, as charge build up ultimately the accelerating potential will be canceled by the voltage build up on the cathode ($V=Q/C$).

Comment: I see you have asked similar questions for a long time now. What is the fundamental underlying question you are trying to get at?

Comment: @JonCuster yes, thanks sir